Correct Solution to Numerical Reasoning Problem
I've been trying to solve this but seem to be missing something. I got 88 but it seems to be the wrong answer.
QUESTION:
If every 2 out of 3 readymade shirts need alterations in the sleeves, and every 4 out of 5 need it in the body, how many alterations will be required for 60 shirts ?
MY SOLUTION:
$(\frac23 + \frac45) * 60 = 88$
WHAT THEY CLAIM TO BE THE CORRECT ANSWER:
$(\frac23 + \frac34 + \frac45) * 60 = 133$
My question is, what is the correct solution and where did they get $\frac34$ from as I don't see it anywhere in the question?

I agree with you OP.  Badly written question if they want that as the answer.  What is the source and are you absolutely sure there is no other information missing from your post?

@StéphaneJaouen thanks for the edit.

@JMoravits Can I include a screenshot or link in my question? I'm mostly familiar with Stack Overflow

This is actually the link to the question

Let this be a reminder that for-profit quizzes like this made by people who are not experts in what they are quizzing about regularly have errors and are written poorly.  Very likely, the question author had a different question in mind where there was the chance for alterations needed to the neck as well and had the answer written already but later decided to change the question to make it less tedious but forgot to change the answer along with it.

@JMoravitz you're right. I'd take it that my solution is correct and this was a mistake on their part.
